# Select-String sometimes results in "System.Object[]"

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm working on a script that combines parts of two text files.  These files are not too large (about 2000 lines each).
I'm seeing strange output from select-string that I don't think should be there.
Here's samples of my two files:

**CC.csv - 2026 lines**

```
LS126L47L6/1L2#519,07448,1,B
LS126L47L6/1R1-1#503,07449,1,B
LS126L47L6/1L3#536,07450,1,B
LS126L47L6/2R1#515,07451,1,B
LS126L47L6/10#525,07452,1,B
LS126L47L6/1L4#538,07453,1,B
```

**GI.txt - 1995 lines**

```
07445,B,SH,1
07446,B,SH,1
07448,B,SH,1
07449,B,SH,1
07450,B,SH,1
07451,B,SH,1
07452,B,SH,1
07453,B,SH,1
07454,B,SH,1
```

And here's a sample of the output file:

**output in myfile.csv**

```
 LS126L47L6/3R1#516,07446,1,B
 LS126L47L6/1L2#519,07448,1,B
 LS126L47L6/1R1-1#503,07449,1,B
 System.Object[],B
 LS126L47L6/2R1#515,07451,1,B
```

This is the script I'm using:

```
sc ./myfile.csv "col1,col2,col3,col4"

$mn = gc cc.csv | select -skip 1 |  % {$_.tostring().split(",")[1]}
$mn | % {
        $a = (gc cc.csv | sls $_ ).tostring() -replace ",[a-z]$", ""
        if (gc GI.txt | sls $_ | select -first 1)
            {$b = (gc GI.txt | sls $_ | select -first 1).tostring().split(",")[1]}
        else {$b = "NULL"
                write-host "$_ is not present in GI file"}
        $c = $a + ',' + $b
        ac ./myfile.csv -value $c
        }
```

The $a variable is where I am sometimes seeing the returned string as **System.Object[]**
Any ideas why?  Also, this script takes quite some time to finish.  Any tips for a newb on how to speed it up?

Edit: I should add that I've taken one line from the cc.csv file, saved in a new text file, and run through the script in console up through assigning $a.  I can't get it to return "system.object[]".

Edit 2:  After follow the advice below and trying a couple of things I've noticed that if I run

`$mn | %{(gc cc.csv | sls $_).tostring()}`

I get System.Object[].
But if I run

`$mn | %{(gc cc.csv | sls $_)} | %{$_.tostring()}`

It comes out fine. Go figure.

Comment: Look at the intermediate results.

Comment: Mainly, the raw value of $a. The problem is `(gc cc.csv | sls $_ )` returns an Object[] (array of Objects, with any length or content). Consider that `(new Object[0]).ToString()` evaluates to "System.Object[]", and *this* is where the strange output is introduced. Now the question becomes why does *that* occur, which is answered by looking at input to, and output from `(gc cc.csv | sls $_ )`.

Comment: The results file, myfile.csv has 16 occurrences of system.object, in seemingly random places.  All of the lines are formatted the same in the two source files.

Comment: Ok, I believe that it's not random.  Just not sure how to isolate it beyond verifying there's no extra formatting characters in the input files.

Comment: It takes hundreds of lines of the file to begin seeing the odd results. However, I copied the lines I show above for cc.csv 600 times into a new file.  On running the relevant script lines in console all I get is "system.object" even though the new file looks fine.

Comment: Consider opening up the file using a *hex editor* (or editor that can show special characters). There might be surprising data that doesn't normally show up as text.

Comment: Ok, I used your reduced script. copy/pasted above six lines from cc.csv into new file. In PS console ran (Get-content newfile.txt) * 300 | set-content cc.csv. I'm using PS4.0 on Win7 64bit.  Running your script produced nothing but System.Object[] strings. Notepad++ shows no extra format characters.  I'll have to dig up a hex editor.

Comment: Looks fine in hex editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by *a change in multiplicity of matches*. If there are multiple matching elements an `Object[]` array (of MatchInfo elements) is returned; a single matching element results in a single `MatchInfo` object (*not* in an array); and when there are no matches, `null` is returned.

Consider these results, when executed against the "cc.csv" test-data supplied:

```powershell
# matches many
(gc cc.csv | Select-String "LS" ).GetType().Name # => Object[]
# matches one
(gc cc.csv | Select-String "538").GetType().Name # => MatchInfo
# matches none
(gc cc.csv | Select-String "FAIL")               # => null
```

The result of calling `ToString` on Object[] is "System.Object[]" while the result is a more useful concatenation of the matched values when invoked directly upon a MatchInfo object.

The immediate problem can be fixed with `selected | Select -First 1`, which will result in a MatchInfo being returned for the first two cases. Select-String will still search the entire input - extra results are simply discarded.

However, it seems like the look-back into "cc.csv" (with the Select-String) could be eliminated entirely as that is where `$_` originally comes from. Here is a minor [untested] adaptation, of what it may look like:

```powershell
gc cc.csv | Select -Skip 1 | %{
    $num = $_.Split(",")[1]
    $a = $_ -Replace ",[a-z]$", ""
    # This is still O(m*n) and could be improved with a hash/set probe.
    $gc_match = Select-String $num -Path gi.csv -SimpleMatch | Select -First 1
    if ($gc_match) {
       # Use of "Select -First 1" avoids the initial problem; but 
       # it /may/ be more appropriate for an error to indicate data problems.
       # (Likewise, an error in the original may need further investigation.)
       $b = $gc_match.ToString().Split(",")[1]
    } else {
       $b = "NULL"
       Write-Host "$_ is not present in GI file"
    }
    $c = $a + ',' + $b
    ac ./myfile.csv -Value $c
}
```

Comment: Ah! Yes, that "Select -First 1" was present because I knew at times I would run into two matches with Select-String.  I haven't tested your suggestion above, but I think it's clear that multiple matches is causing the problem, so I'll mark as answered.  - Thanks a bunch!!